# Issue with changing the background image using the .css() jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I am using the .css() jQuery method to change the background of a div with an ID of "background". The method accepts as parameters the property name and the value you want to set for it. Therefore, my code is as follows:

```
function changeBackground() {
      $("#background").css("background-image", "url(../assets/background2.jpg)");
}

window.onload = function() {
      window.addEventListener("click", changeBackground);
};
```

Originally, `background-image` had a value of `url(../assets/background.jpg)`. The curious thing is that it works fine in the Chrome session that my editor (Brackets.io) uses as Live Preview, but it doesn't when I open Chrome normally or I use Firefox and Opera.

**EDIT:** The issue was with the path: instead of temporarily changing the value in the css sheet (what I thought the code did), apparently jQuery itself makes sure the background source changes. This means that the path for the image must be set relative to the javascript file—in this case `url(assets/background2.jpg)` instead of `url(../assets/background2.jpg)`. I'd like anyone more knowledgeable or better spoken to correct me if needed.

However, another issue arose—the rest of the styling for the background image (see below) gets completely ignored after jQuery changed its source. How can you fix this?

```
#background {
background-image: url(../assets/background.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;    
position: fixed;
top: 0em;
left: 0em;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
margin: 0em;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the relative path is correct? Also you seem to be using an odd mix of native JS and jQuery. It's best to stick to one.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path and checked your console for errors? Can you reproduce the issue with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: @j08691 The console told me that the problem was the path—I fixed it as shown in my edit. Apparently it's still relative, but to JS file, not the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Use ' instead of " :

```
$("#background").css("background-image", 'url(../assets/background2.jpg)');
```

If doesn't work, try this

```
$("#background").css({backgroundImage : 'url(../assets/background2.jpg)'});
```

or this

```
$("#background").css('background', 'url("../assets/background2.jpg")');
```

Answer (score 0):

add class .new-background

```
// css
.new-background {
    background-image: url(../assets/background2.jpg);
}
```

and

```
// js
function changeBackground() {
  $("#background").addClass('new-background');
}

$(window).click(changeBackground);
```

Comment: // css
.new-background {
    background-image: url(../assets/background2.jpg) !important;
}   )))))))